# Declaring list with variable

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

Quick one, why does this not work? How do I get it to work?

```
int iSize = 10;
float fList[iSize];
```

The above returns:

> array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C language doesn't let us do that; it wants a fixed array dimension at compile-time. Try `const int iSize = 10;` to make your `iSize` a constant.

Answer (score 2):

this subject is called VLA (variable length array) 
many C compilers prevent's you from doing that 
you can either use pointer instead of array (if you want to resize it) 
or use "const" key word (or #define which is probably better regarding arduino memory limitations)